# Switching the cell position in Tableview in JAVAFX

Tags: javafx, tableview

Is it possible to switch the row position in a `TableView` in javafx.

Suppose I created a 5 rows and and there is two button as "UP" and "DOWN". On click of UP button user can swap the particular selected row to upward direction and for DOWN button user can move the row to downward position on click of DOWN button; i.e. user can place the particlar selected row to any position in `TableView` using `Button` clicks. Is that possible in `TableView` using javafx? If its possible kindly provide me a logic to do that.

Comment: Yes, of course. Just move the item to a different position in the table's items list.

Comment: Suppose i created a 5 rows  and and there is two button as "UP" and "DOWN".. on click of UP button user can swap the particular selected row to upward direction and for DOWN button user can move the row to downward position on click of DOWN button. ie. user can place the particlar selectyed row to any position on click of button in TableView.. is that possible in tableview using javafx?? if its possible kindly provide me a logic to do that...

Answer (score 5):

You can simply modify the `items` of the `TableView` to achieve this effect:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    TableView<Item<String>> tableView = createTableView();

    Button upButton = new Button("Up");
    Button downButton = new Button("Down");

    ReadOnlyIntegerProperty selectedIndex = tableView.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty();

    upButton.disableProperty().bind(selectedIndex.lessThanOrEqualTo(0));
    downButton.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
        int index = selectedIndex.get();
        return index < 0 || index+1 >= tableView.getItems().size();
    }, selectedIndex, tableView.getItems()));

    upButton.setOnAction(evt -> {
        int index = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        // swap items
        tableView.getItems().add(index-1, tableView.getItems().remove(index));
        // select item at new position
        tableView.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(index-1);
    });

    downButton.setOnAction(evt -> {
        int index = tableView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        // swap items
        tableView.getItems().add(index+1, tableView.getItems().remove(index));
        // select item at new position
        tableView.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(index+1);
    });

    BorderPane root = new BorderPane(tableView);
    root.setRight(new VBox(10, upButton, downButton));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```